# Kubernetes - Consul - Envoy - How to set up load balancing algorithm?

Tags: kubernetes, consul, envoyproxy

I'm trying to setup sticky grpc communications using consul/envoy. Somehow load balance algorithm stays random, cannot apply it to my service.

Official consul documentation got me this far. What am I doing wrong?

```
apiVersion: 'v1'
kind: 'Service'
metadata:
  name: grpc-test-load-balancer
  labels:
    app: grpc-loadbalancer
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: 'TCP'
      port: 18788
      targetPort: 18788
  selector:
    app: 'grpc-test'
  type: 'LoadBalancer'
  loadBalancerIP: ''
---
apiVersion: consul.hashicorp.com/v1alpha1
kind: ServiceResolver
metadata:
  name: grpc-test-load-balancer
spec:
  loadBalancer:
    policy: maglev
    hashPolicies:
      - field: "cookie"
        fieldValue : "brown-cookie"
```

Comment: Is the configuration entry properly synced to Consul (`kubectl get serviceresolver grpc-test-load-balancer)`? Are you connecting to the service using the upstream port you defined in [`connect-service-upstreams`](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/connect#consul-hashicorp-com-connect-service-upstreams), or are you still trying to connect to it using the IP returned from Kube DNS?

Comment: A-ha, I didn't use connect-service upstreams in my configuration, I was just connecting with pod name - dns. I'll try this first thing tomorrow.

Comment: @BlakeCovarrubias should i change anything else in my serviceresolver?

Comment: It should definitely work when using the local upstream. FYI, Consul 1.10 will support connecting to upstreams by their service / pod DNS name. Watch https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/issues/23 for updates on this.

Comment: your service resolver config looks good to me. Its formatted correctly as per the Kubernetes YAML example at https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/config-entries/service-resolver#consistent-load-balancing.

Comment: Hey @BlakeCovarrubias, I tried to add annotations to client, server yaml files but unfortunately couldn't get it working.

Comment: Did you also reconfigure your application to connect to the upstream at localhost:<port>?

Comment: @BlakeCovarrubias The thing is, I dont know much about upstreams. My setup is like this: grpc client connects to this service by dns name:port, and load balancer forwards it to the grpc server at the back. grpc server is a deployment, and i test the sticky session by scaling that. Should I be doing something else?

Comment: You'd need to configure the app to instead connect to localhost:<port>, where port is what you have configured in the `connect-service-upstreams` annotation. For example, if the port is 1234, the proxy will listen on that port. When it receives connections on that port, it will forward the connection over the mesh to the upstream service. See https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/kubernetes-secure-agents?in=consul/kubernetes for a detailed tutorial. In Consul 1.10 you will be able to dial the service over dns_name:port, and that traffic will be automatically redirected to the sidecar.

Comment: I see you posted at https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-use-maglev-load-balancing-in-kubernetes-grpc/21332. Lets continue the discussion there.